# Scrolling page content

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem: I have a web page with a table. When I set the vertical position of the table to top:00, the table is "cut" by half - only the upper part is displayed and the bottom not because a scroll bar doesn't appear...
Here is the code:

```
 <table id="eln">...</table>
```

CSS:

```
#eln{
    text-align:center;
    width:800px;
     margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    position:relative; 
    top:400px; 
    font-size:19;
}
```

So, how to make the code so to scroll the page and to see the whole table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have your table inside of another container that is cutting it off.

It's hard to say because you haven't included all the markup.  It is generally helpful to include all the code and create a jsFiddle to illustrate problems you are having.

Comment: the table is 180 rows... :) You can see it here: http://chemref.free.bg/electronegativity.html

Comment: There is no table with 180 rows on that page.

Comment: Well thanks for the advice... after rechecking the code i found a <div> that was "packing" the menu and the table

Answer (score 0):

Position: relative; top: 400px will position your table 400px *lower* as if it were in the normal flow (position: static).

You need position: absolute (in this case, the margin-*: auto are unneeded) or position: static (in this case top:, right:, are irrelevant).